# What a data type to use for multidimensional array

Tags: typescript

I have a function that creates a dynamic multidimensional level with unpredictable number of dimensions. I wonder what a type I should declare as a return value. E.g. when I declare Promise, I get the following error when the array gets 2 dimensions:

```
Type 'ITest[][]' is not assignable to type 'ITest[]'
```

Is is possible to declare type as a multidimensional array with arbitrary number of level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. But this is effectively what type `any` if for. If you array can have many different structures in it, then its of type `any[]`.

```
type arr = any[];

const a:arr = [[1], [[2], [[3], [[4]]]]];
```